# How do I reference a dynamically generated symbol?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to dynamically create functions based on some `static` `public` fields of a Java class. So in one file I have something like:

```
(intern *ns* (symbol (get-fieldname-from-class class)) some-func)
```

The problem is that I want to call that particular function while it isn't defined yet.

For example, the Java class has a static int `PARENTHESIZED_EXPRESSION` field. From this I generate a `parenthesized-expression?` function. This works quite nice, but when I load a Clojure file in the `REPL` that uses this functions I get an

> unable to resolve parenthesized-expression?

error. So I have to make sure that the symbol's are interned first. How can I do this?

I realize this is not a very functional approach, but I'm a little bit hesitant to enter almost 80 similar functions for all the fields of this class. Besides, this class might be subject to change.

Comment: calling a static public static field of a class is simple : `Class/fieldName` Why do you need to go this complex way to create functions for them?

Comment: I know, but I want to replace lots of (= (.getNodeType expr) ASTNode/PARENTHESIZED_EXPRESSION)) like constructs by (parenthesized-expression? expr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you could get by using a macro like this:

```
user=> (defmacro f [sym] `(defn ~(symbol (str sym "?")) [x#] (= x# ~(symbol (str "java.util.Calendar/" (str sym))))))
#'user/f
user=> (f DAY_OF_MONTH)
#'user/DAY_OF_MONTH?
user=> (DAY_OF_MONTH? java.util.Calendar/DAY_OF_WEEK)
false
user=> (DAY_OF_MONTH? java.util.Calendar/DAY_OF_MONTH)
true
user=>
```

Comment: I used a variant of this defmacro. Thanks.